# Is there Solar Eclipse in Terraria Mobile 1.2?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have the mobile version of Terraria and I want the [Broken Hero Sword](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Broken_Hero_Sword).

Is the [Solar Eclipse](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Solar_Eclipse) event included in the iPhone version?

Comment: If the Terraria wiki page you're looking at doesn't have the console/desktop only disclaimer banner on top, it usually means whatever the page is about appears in all platform the game is on

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, the Solar Eclipse is there.

The Solar Eclipse was introduced in the PC 1.2 update.

If we take a look at the [Mobile Version History](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_Version_History), we can see the latest update:

> 1.2 Update
>   (1.2.1 PC equivalent)

Since it is equivelant to the PC 1.2.1 patch, that means that the Solar Eclipse has been added.